# Is it possible to configure a router, to have two connections, one direct connection to the ISP (normal) and one through a proxy?

Tags: networking, router, proxy

Im a little new to this.. 
I need my router to give me two options when attempting to route my traffic one normal and one though a preconfigured proxy.. I am aware of firmware such as DDRWT but have never used it before and don't know what to expect..
Any help is appreciated...please..
Thanx

Comment: I don't believe either of these answers addresses your question. You should update your question with the additional details found in the comments sections of these answers. I think I have an answer for you on the router level. I'll be back later to provide it.

Comment: Nevermind, you have a history of not accepting answers...

Comment: No, no.. most people just did not understand some of my past questions ..  I would be delighted if you post your answer ill upvote you too...  and hey even if I dont like it its the knowledge what is important..

Comment: @Tim_Stewart  Wait... I visited this page now.. and I cant see anything I had said that implies unacceptence . I even said " very valuable information"... perhaps u mean another link?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart  oh, u mean clicking the green tick dont u... yeah I wasnt really aware of it

Comment: Ah, this confusion came from you **not** taking the superuser tour in the help section... Go get your **informed** badge dude!

Answer (score 2):

> I need my router to give me two options when attempting to route my traffic one normal and one though a preconfigured proxy..

You can set this up in various ways (e.g. a VLAN for the proxy), but it's not straightforward. Why do you think your **router** needs to provide this option, and not something else?

What kind of proxy is this? A VPN? A http proxy? Something else?

Most importantly: how do you decide for applications if they should use the direct connection, or the proxy?

Details on how to set this up will depend on those question.

---

> its really very simple, I want a system that automatically pushes certain websites to VPN.

So it's about a VPN, and the router has nothing to do with it.

And it's actually not simple, because you want to mix different networking levels (webpage requests are on layer 7, routing is on layer 3).

Assuming that you want to read the certain websites on a single PC, and assuming that PC runs Linux, and assuming that the VPN also runs on that PC, install a transparent proxy on that PC that can mark packages (for example squid with [tcp_outgoing_mark](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v6/cfgman/tcp_outgoing_mark.html)), then set up firewall rules which send the marked packages through the network interface of your VPN software, and the rest directly to your ISP.

If your PC runs Windows, find out the Windows equivalent to that, or use an additional device that runs Linux (see below).

If you want to do this for multiple PCs, use an additional device that runs Linux, and set up the whole thing there. This can, but need not be, your router, if you can install additional software on it, and if it has enough RAM etc. Yes, in that case you need to install some kind open firmware like OpenWRT or DDRWT on it.

Anyhow, the whole thing needs a lot of networking experience. So be prepared to do a lot of reading, and to learn about these things. No, I can't give you a "just follow blindly those steps, no need to understand them" answer, too much depends on your actual system.

Comment: Http proxy...  I guess one way to do it is use direct connection by default except for the websites I preconfigured in a list.. do most routers support that ability? Im not sure..

Comment: No router provides that ability in their firmware. If you want to switch based on website address, you need to install and configure a transparent http proxy on the router, which you only can do by installing a new firmware. A much simpler option is to install a transparent http proxy on your PC (assuming you only want this for one PC, you didn't tell us).

Comment: no, I want this applied every device (tablets, phones,smart tv)..

Comment: I just read up about transparent http proxy stuff... I dont think its a great solution because my connection will be slower going though two proxys

Comment: I intend to preconfigure the system to use direct connection automatically for websites except for certain  websites preconfigured ... so is a Vlan Ideal?

Comment: If you refuse to give any details about your actual use case, and just ask questions about the solutions you imagine would work for it, I am afraid I cannot help you. Please read up on [XY questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your Y is "I need to configure my router", but we need you to describe your X.

Comment: And if VLan is ideal can I turn an old pc into a VLan ? What software would I need? ... (My needs is that it rout a list of websites to VPN automatically when I visit them..)

Comment: I am sorry, I believed that i provided enough info on my use... its really very simple, I want a system that automatically pushes certain websites to VPN.. ( so that i dont have to install VPN software in every device in my home.. someone said to setup a VLan but I don’t know how to do that.. Thank you for your time..

Comment: (yes i want this system to affect all my connected devices)            I see, well good thing it is actually possible on the router level; I really dont want to deal with Linux even if it came down to that I would rather use an old netbook running windows if it’s possible. Also I did not find any guides regarding  this idea,  So im probably going to post here any obstacles im facing when i come down to it...           Sorry for the bad phrasing of the original question..

Comment: But you'll have to deal with Linux when setting this up on your router - your router runs Linux, you need a package manage to install `squid`, you need `iptables` to set up the firewall (or use OpenWRT config files), etc...

Comment: Alright.. ill ask about that in another question when its time for it..

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a website on the internet, through a proxy would still be through your ISP.

You need two different IP addresses, so the router can make the distinction.

The routing table of the router would then route one IP out one interface and one out another.

Comment: "The routing table of the router would then route one IP out one interface and one out another.The routing table of the router would then route one IP out one interface and one out another."  Pls explain more in detail.. Also what would that setup be called?

Comment: I know that it would still be through my isp.. but you get the idea..  I simply want the router to use the proxy in some occasions and Connect directly in others..

Comment: @Hosa I still had to correct you. And if you know it's still through the ISP then you should have phrased yourself more correctly. Also technically if your proxy was internal and you were accessing something internal through your proxy then it wouldn't be via your ISP

Comment: If you are asking  how would I suggest doing it (or to use this website's language, then 'how', then my answer doesn't really cover that but your question asks is it possible. And my answer covers that and shows how it is possible.. That said, one thing I have done re accessing through a proxy on/off, is some software on my computer to do it, though not a setting in the router. And a website called `hidemyass.com` had a solution i used to use. Some software to enable/disable whether my connection went through a proxy.

Comment: @Hosa what i'd suggest you try is try some proxy or vpn solutions, and see if they have on/off features and what people do to turn them on/off,  i'd suggest that that's a good route for you  to take

Comment: I dont want to bother my self with software as my home has several devices.. I need to do it on the router level

Comment: @Hosa You you get a router that can support a VPN and you can turn it on and off in your router's configuration.

Comment: that would be nice ..was not aware that was an option..  does ddwrt support that?  Because I dont want to buy a new one

Comment: @Hosa well I see things on google for ddwrt configure vpn